# Alamofire garbage at end error while parsing json

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm connecting to my server on localhost to fetch some data. The data returned to this request is a JSON, on **Postman** the JSON is correctly shown, but when I'm playing with iOS, Alamofire returns me an error:

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))

The JSON in question is:

```
{
  "name": "TestName",
  "surname": "TestSurname"
}
```

The thing that I do not understand is that if I force my server to return the json in form of a string so something like

```
"{"name": "TestName after update","surname": "TestSurname"}"
```

Alamofire does not complain and parses it correctly. How is that? I thought that specifying the parameter `responseJSON` it would have worked the other way around.

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.4:8080/user/abcdf").validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                // DO stuff

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just checked the JSON by creating a json-server and it worked fine

Comment: But i added the JSON into an Object, like that : [
{
name: "TestName",
surname: "TestSurname"
}
]

Comment: So probably it's the way the JSON is generated, will dig into it

Comment: That's definitely not a Alamofire bug. Check the answer from server.

Answer (score 5):

This means your API response string is not a proper JSON. **Ensure your response is valid JSON.** In my case (below), JSON String had some HTML characters which broke the JSON.

[image]

If you are using Alamofire, change .responseJSON to .responseString and verify the response structure is valid JSON.

**Note : if you are using Postman, you may not notice the extra unwanted character in JSON response. You need to change the response type from "Pretty" to "Raw" to observe this.**

Comment: It worked for me. My temporary debug code was unwanted character in JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the data so you should have it written like this I am not sure though

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.4:8080/user/abcdf",method:.get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
          //do stuff   

        }
        else {

           // do other stuff 
        }
    }
```